# Geographic -> UTM Raster Rectification

Tags: google-earth, coordinate-system, gdalwarp, utm

I'm trying to use an image overlay in KML / Google Earth as the basis for adding extra info and returning this to Google Earth.

In my utility app I can specify a rectangle to give me the north-south-east-west for the overlay and get the image, I then write this to a KML file as an overlay. (I can open this KML file in Google Earth and see that the overlay is nicely aligned).

I then import this KML file into my main app, which is a planar system. Thus I convert to UTM. The intention is to add info (i.e., draw on the image) and then export back from UTM to lat/long in another KML file. However, the 'rectangular' corners of the image in lat/long are not rectangular in UTM - so I need a transform in there some how.

How can this be achieved? Are the corners sufficient as GCPs? How do I calculate the necessary rotation/skew for the image? Is that even what I need to do?

(as you can tell, I'm no GIS expert!)

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be much simpler than I thought. I already knew my 'rectangular' UTM coordinates and the 'real' UTM location of the corners. I could then use that info along with the image size to calculate the pixel positions of the 'real' corners and use those to warp the image.